# How to change a class to the nodeValue of the element? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, scroller

I want to change the effect (class) of my scroller to the effect on the button a user clicks. Here's my code:

```
var scroller=$('#main ul.stroll'); --> I know this is right.. just a var reference

function effectSelect(e){

    var target = $(e.currentTarget);

    $(target).click(function(){
        var effectName=target.nodeValue;
        var effect='stroll ' + effectName;
        scroller.removeClass();
        scroller.addClass(effect);
    })
}
```

It worked at a certain point then suddenly stopped working. There are no errors in the console when I run it. What am I doing wrong? Let me know if you need more info

Comment: `target` is a jQuery object, it doesn't have `nodeValue` property! When you have a jQuery object you use `text` or `html` method instead.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Just kinda getting into JQuery/Javascript. What would I use instead? .html?

Comment: Gracias, amigo! How do I upvote you on here?

Comment: use `e.currentTarget` (is the native JS version of `target`). However I'm not sure if the logic is correct. You should use the `target` taken from the `ev` argument passed in the click handler.

Comment: So I should use e.target instead of e.currentTarget? and do you mean put the e within the click function arguments, not the  initial effectSelect arguments?

Comment: How do you call the `effectSelect` function? Do you know each time the function is called you attach another click handler to the `e.currentTarget` element?

Comment: You know, I didn't even think of that. I just thought it would be firing as soon as I clicked on a button.

And if by click handler you mean add a different class to the element, then yes that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally. Hope this helps anyone in a similar situation!

```
function init(event) {

    stroll.bind($scroller);

    $('.nav li').on('click', function(event){
        var target = $(event.target);
        var effectName = target.text();
        var effect = 'stroll ' + effectName;
        $scroller.removeClass();
        $scroller.addClass(effect);

        console.log($scroller.attr('class'))
    });

}
```